# how to convert a fetch row to a single string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

For inputs of a postgis function, I used a cursor to fetch a record at once from a table.

I know that the single record can be printed by the code: FETCH 1 FROM cur1. I wonder how to convert the fetched result into a single string.

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT rec FROM Table;
FETCH 1 FROM cur1;
                    rec
---------------------------------------
 vehicles
(1 row)
END;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can concat string in format: `string || string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert row to text just by casting it to `text`:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t.*::text FROM Table t;
FETCH 1 FROM cur1;
```

Row values will be separated by comma and whole row will be enclosed into parenthesis.

If you also want column names it is possible to convert row to JSON:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT row_to_json(t.*) FROM Table t;
FETCH 1 FROM cur1;
```

Comment: yes, the codes can convert row to text, but they cannot used in the cursor situation.

Comment: Why not? Just prepend `DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR` and you will get a cursor.

Comment: how do you select the table? I used cur1 as the table (SELECT t.rec::text FROM cur1 t), but it does not work, showing: relation "cur1" does not exist. If I selected the original table, all records are showed, instead of just 1 by 1.

Comment: I just updated my answer with full commands. Hope this will be more clear.

Comment: One more issue that I cannot use the results of FETCH 1 FROM cur1 for string functions, if I set more than one cursor. For example, SELECT (FETCH 1 FROM cur_1)||","||FETCH 1 FROM cur_2), although the cursors are in text.

Comment: `fetch` does not fit into `select`. You can join two tables when declaring cursor: `declare ... select (t1.*::text)||','||(t2.*::text) from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.xx = t2.yy`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57633/discussion-between-max-taldykin-and-vicky).